Make it flow smoothly to add a post to a specific saves list
I am an avid user of the saves feature. I like it. I want to love it. One of the biggest pain points is how much I need to move my mouse around to add a post to a specific list.

saves button is to the left of the post.
toast notification shows up at the top, with "manage" button in the right side of the toast.
dialogue pops up in the middle of the screen, with no autofocus, even (see Make clicking "manage" after saving a post auto-focus the list-selection dropdown).

I sometimes use a mouse. Fine- I have to do a dance around my screen hitting some not-very-large buttons to get what I want.
I sometimes use a trackpoint. This hurts. It doesn't hurt that much doing it once. But I use this feature a lot. I would not be surprised if I and NotTheDr01ds are the most heavy users of the feature. You could say "just don't use a trackpoint"... but you could also make the UX flow smoother.
I... don't have any particular bright ideas on how exactly to do this right now. Opening for discussion. Basically, I want to not have to move my mouse around so much to add a post to a specific saves list when using a mouse (I also use my keyboard the other 50% of the time, but that's another story).

I don't know why they don't just put it next to the "Follow" link in the contextual links at the bottom of the post. The Follow link opens a nice pop-up right under the link which itself contains links to manage your follows. I think the reason is to match the behavior of the previous "Favorites" feature. But the favorites feature was publicly accessible (like how vote buttons are semi-public) while saves is totally private like follows.

@CaveJohnson are you using a userscript? the follow link just toggles following for me.

https://i.sstatic.net/8M9adxsT.png That's what it's supposed to show. These popups were added with the "Follow" feature, previously buttons only used just the basic title (share/edit/flag/etc still do)

Yes what VLAZ said. Also I guess they don't necessarily have to move saves, just add a popoover like what the follow link does.

@CaveJohnson sorry. something was wrong with my brain at that moment :P you're right, and I think that's a good direction for this request
